# Get all rows after doing GroupBy in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to do group by in SparkSQL which works good but most of the rows went missing.

```
  spark.sql(
"""
  | SELECT
  | website_session_id,
  | MIN(website_pageview_id) as min_pv_id
  |
  | FROM website_pageviews
  | GROUP BY website_session_id
  | ORDER BY website_session_id
  |
  |
  |""".stripMargin).show(10,truncate = false)
```

I am getting output like this :

```
+------------------+---------+
|website_session_id|min_pv_id|
+------------------+---------+
|1                 |1        |
|10                |15       |
|100               |168      |
|1000              |1910     |
|10000             |20022    |
|100000            |227964   |
|100001            |227966   |
|100002            |227967   |
|100003            |227970   |
|100004            |227973   |
+------------------+---------+
```

Same query in MySQL gives the desired result like this :

[image]

What is the best way to do ,so that all rows are fetched in my Query.

***Please note** I already checked other answers related to this, like joining to get all rows etc, but I want to know if there is any other way by with we can get the result like we get in MySQL ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is ordered by alphabetically, in which case 10 comes before 2.
You might want to check that the columns type is a number, not string.
What datatypes do the columns have (printSchema())?

Comment: The problem was I was not using inferSchema when reading my CSV, hence the issue. Anyway thanks for pointing me to the right direction @Gerold Busch

Answer (score 1):

I think website_session_id is of string type. Cast it to an integer type and see what you get:

```
spark.sql(
"""
  | SELECT
  | CAST(website_session_id AS int) as website_session_id,
  | MIN(website_pageview_id) as min_pv_id
  |
  | FROM website_pageviews
  | GROUP BY website_session_id
  | ORDER BY website_session_id
  |
  |
  |""".stripMargin).show(10,truncate = false)
```